# How do I format text displayed in a tooltip expression when hovering over an image in ssrs?

Tags: text, reporting-services, tooltip

I'm trying to have descriptive text show up on a tool tip when hovering over an image. However the text shows up in a single long line in a window across the screen.  How do I add line breaks and control the text font/size in the tooltip expression.  Also, the tooltip window needs to be displayed until the user moves the mouse off the image.  Can this be done using html or java expressions? Am I better off trying to create a small collapsible tablix with the desired text as the child group?

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and my expression looks like this:

```
="Description: All trees or conditions inspected that yield a 
  rating of 10, 11, or 12, should have a Work Order created. 
  There are Inspections of priority A or B that do not have a 
  Work Order.  
  Logic: INSPs are selected for this metric if the following is true:

 -The INSP has a Risk Rating of 10,11,12 from RISKASSESSMENT_EVW

 -The INSP does not have a matching Inspection Global ID in WORKORDER_EVW

 -The INSP has an Inspection Date that is NOT NULL in INSPECTION_EVW"
```

I want to have line breaks after each logic descriptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a linebreak by inserting the VB constant `vbcrlf` which is basically an old school carriage return, line feed insertion.  Break each line apart with a closing quote and use the `&` symbol to concatenate.  So the expression would look something like the following.

```
="Description: All trees or conditions inspected that yield a rating of 10, 11, or 12, 
should have a Work Order created. There are Inspections of priority A or B that do not 
have a Work Order." & vbcrlf & 
"Logic: INSPs are selected for this metric if the following is true: " & vbcrlf & 
" -The INSP has a Risk Rating of 10,11,12 from RISKASSESSMENT_EVW" & vbcrlf & 
" -The INSP does not have a matching Inspection Global ID in WORKORDER_EVW" & vbcrlf & 
" -The INSP has an Inspection Date that is NOT NULL in INSPECTION_EVW"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, this works great.  Do you know if you can format text in here with VB commands as well?

Comment: @KurtCederholm If you mean formatting the text in a tooltip as bold or italics, no, it's not possible to do this inline.  You may be able to define custom code and write a function to do what you'd like, but SSRS may have trouble with that.  You'd be able to call it in the expression like `Code.[YourFunctionName]("Text to format")`.  That's a whole 'nother question though and I'd recommend posting up a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks @Steve-o169 I really appreciate the help.